# QGIS 3.16 DXF to GeoJSON loses extents

Tags: qgis, geojson, extents, dxf

I am trying to export a DXF file with polygon outline letters to GeoJSON to place on a map at a certain latitude and longitude. I was hoping to set the project type () and the extents to do this but the resulting GeoJSON file does not contain any extents and it not a vector layer as I would expect.

Here is the DXF file with extents:

[image]

Here is where I set the projection (EPSG:4326 - WGS 84) and the extents:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Source extent does not transform directly into EPSG:4326. See the coordinate ranges: 15-581 and 135-594. Another error is in your output limits: minY and maxY are both the same.

Comment: Okay, I will check the coordinate ranges. Is there more information related to this to deepen my understanding? Also, good catch on the north and south being the same.

Comment: If I understand right you have a CAD file that is not georeferenced but somehow you know where on Earth it should be located. You could have a try with ogr2ogr and ground control points `-gcp` https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html. Three of four ground control points should be enough.

Comment: @user30184 - I am just trying to understand where the coordinate ranges you suggested come from: 15-581 and 135-594 ? They seem random from my uneducated prospective and I would like to learn more. Also, you are correct I have a CAD file that I am trying to locate on the Earth. I will also look at ogr2org!

Comment: Actually I wrote the ranges wrong. The extent inside the red box in your first image is minx, miny, maxx, maxy so the ranges are 15-135 and 581-594. I guess that coordinates (0 0) are either at the top left or at the lower left corner of some virtual drawing paper. Test data would help.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are saying that the source extent does not transform directly into EPSG:4326, but then what are the Current Extent options in QGIS for then: Current Layer Extent, Calculate from Layer, and Map Canvas Extent within the Save Vector Layer dialog? It appears they are to set the extents of the input source based on the CRS.

Comment: @bdelliott, you need to know the CRS definition of the DXF drawing and assign it to the layer, then you can reproject it. The coordinates of the extents of the DXF, in what CRS must be interpreted? Clearly not geographic coordinates.